# Select Query returns NULL when using PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to send few file names to server via php script from ios device using json.

I can send file names and receive them back if  I use:

```
    $handle = fopen('php://input','r');
    $jsonInput = fgets($handle);
    $decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);

    sendResponse(200, json_encode($decoded));
```

I sent a json string from ios like= `["sample.pdf","sample-1.pdf"]`
sendResponse 200 is in ios device which proves my send and receive methods working=

```
(
    "sample.pdf",
    "sample-1.pdf"
)
```

However If I change the code to below and try to run a query I always get `Query failed`

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
var_dump($decoded);
$names = join("', '",$decoded);
var_dump($names);

$sql = new mysqli($config['localhost'], $config['xxx'], $config['xxxx'], $config['xxxxx']);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE name IN ('$names')";
$result = $sql->query($query);     
if (!$result) {
    var_dump($result);
    //printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    //sendResponse(417, json_encode("Query failed:"));
    sendResponse(417, json_encode($decoded));

exit;
}

    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $rows[]=$row;
    }
sendResponse(200, json_encode($decoded));

$result->close();
$sql->close();
```

From the above code I always get `Query failed` response, but real strange thing is that I also get `NULL` response from `sendResponse(417, json_encode($decoded))` or `sendResponse(200, json_encode($decoded));`

Why do I get `null` after query, after all I did not change `$decode` variable?

Why does the query fails?

***EDIT:::::***

removing removing vardumbs for correct json result and changing connection code to this solved the problem know I can get correct query result.

```
$sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular error that it gives as per mysqli_connect_error()?

Comment: Could you, please, do a `echo $query;` and show us the value printed?

Comment: Instead of var_dump(names), put an echo $names, just to see if it is well constructed

Comment: Are you getting that error when you load the page in the browser? Check that the output is a well-formed json (that var_dump, for instance, would break it), because the device might not be able to parse it and might be returning null

Comment: @Alex yes commenting out `$vardumbs` worked for the `null` value part now I can get `$decoded` result in device, but still query fails.

Comment: If you run exactly that query in another tool, like phpmyadmin, does it return exactly what you would expect?

Comment: @pal4life no it doesnt send any connection errors, its just enter the if block saying that query fails.

Comment: @Alex this in phpmayadmin `SELECT *
FROM FILES
WHERE name
IN (
"sample.pdf", "sample-1.pdf"
)` gives two rows as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are mixing the syntax of mysqli.

```
$sql = new mysqli($config['localhost'], $config['xxx'], $config['xxxx'],   $config['xxxxx']);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
```

You should use the object oriented notation to correspond to using new. Also, how you are writing the config seems kind of strange, are you sure the contents of the config are being obtained correctly?

Comment: credentials are correct but change the method to `$sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) ` solved the problem